# while loop outputting no correct falue

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create a python program that is going to ask for students name and grades but I need to validate these marks assuming the exam is out-of 20 so the mark shouldn't be less than zero or grater than 20 so I am using a while loop to do so but when I run it every mark gives an error here is my code

```
Student_Name = [str]
Test1 = [int]

for i in range(3):
Student_Name = raw_input("please input the name of Student {}: ".format(i+1))
Test1 = raw_input("please input the mark for Test1 of {}: ".format(Student_Name))
while Test1 > 20 or Test1 <0:
    print "invalid"
    Test1 = raw_input("please Reinput mark of {}: ".format(Student_Name))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues with the supplied code. First, the indentation is off for the for loop. Second, you have used the same names for both the lists named `Student_Name1` and `Test1` and the input variables named `Student_Name1` and `Test1`. Third, `raw_input` in Python returns a `str`, you need to cast it to an `int`.

```
student_names = [str]
tests = [int]

for i in range(3):
    student_name = raw_input("please input the name of Student {}: ".format(i+1))
    test_score = int(raw_input("please input the mark for Test1 of {}: ".format(student_name)))
        while test_score > 20 or test_score < 0:
        print "invalid"
        test_score = int(raw_input("please Reinput mark of {}: ".format(student_name)))
```

This code should provide what you are looking for, or at least a good reference.